exe built by Pyinstaller not working, stating QtGui not found
I am trying to create an exe file from a python script that uses NodeGraphQt, PySide2 and Qt,
but the created exe won't open and simply give me this error
C:\dev\isp-pipeline_revamp\Utils\ISP_Pipeline_Creator\dist>isp_graph_creator.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ISP_Pipeline_Creator\isp_graph_creator.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "Qt.py", line 2036, in <module>
  File "Qt.py", line 2014, in _install
AttributeError: module 'Qt' has no attribute 'QtGui'
[14784] Failed to execute script 'isp_graph_creator' due to unhandled exception!


I tried to edit the .spec file with 'Qt' as hidden import
I tried using Py2Exe instead but also did not work
I tried to uninstall and install all the Qt dependencies but that also did not work.


In my code I used:
from Qt import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

and it appears there was a Qt dependancy clash, so I changed it to:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

and it worked.
